# Magnific Popup show background image while loading fullres image

Tags: magnific-popup

I am using the zoom function of Magnificic Popup:

```
<a class="image-popup-no-margins" href="photo.jpg"><img src="thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
```

I would like to see thumbnail.jpg as the background of photo.jpg while photo.jpg loads right over it. So you click thumbnail.jpg and then a big version of thumbnail shows up, as it is already in cache, and photo.jpg loads right on top of it.

Is that possible? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Place this before the links you have on page:

```
<div style="display: none;">
  <img src="photo.jpg" />
</div>
```

and then use library like http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload to preload the image.

Comment: "before the links", how does this hidden `div` give me the desired result?